How do I extract ''1,4,8,12, 16..... ''from a list of ''1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16'' on r?
How do I extract ''1,4,8,12, 16..... ''from a list of ''1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16'' on r code?
Currently, I have already tried
a<-1:16

and I have done the first method:
b<-a[seq(1,length(a), 4)]
The results I get from the first method is

1   5   9  13

c<-a[seq(1,length(a), 3)]
The results I got from the second method is:

1   4   7  10  13  16

** Is there a way I can set the function to get '1,4,8,12,16' on r ? Thanks everyone**

Hi @JayBird, it will be helpful for others if you provide the complete information about your question, In what language you are writing and by provide the appropriate Title to your Question.

There is no immediately clear pattern in the sequence 1,4,8,12,16,...
There is of course a clear pattern in the sequence 4,8,12,16,... like you have already figured out; the numbers are divisible by 4.
The '1' in the original list is not part of the sequence generated by this pattern. You could manually put this in front of the sequence 4,8,12,16,... like this:
list_of_1_to_16 <- 1:16
desired_list<-list_of_1_to_16[c(1,seq(4,16, 4))]

In 'seq(4,16,4)', the first argument is the starting number, the second argument is the highest number (as long as it is divisible by 4) and 4 is the step size.
